# how can i add condition to not run when branch to merge into is master and PR number does not contain null

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Im trying to use 3 conditions to run a stage but getting syntax errors, how can i use 3 conditions in a pipeline to run a stage as below . I dont want the stage to run if merging into master is this the correct variable?

```
and(succeeded('Build'),ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'),  ne(variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber'], ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
condition: and(succeeded('Build'), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'),  ne(variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber'], ''))
```

Comment: Hi itye1970; that looks like exactly the same expression (except for an extra space)